# How do i eagerly initialize beans per tenant?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to write a multi-tenant Spring Boot application but having trouble to eager initialize beans when the server starts (i.e. not lazily once the tenant requests the bean)

To support multi-tenancy, i created a `@CustomerScoped` annotation that creates objects based on a ThreadLocal String value.

My configuration provides a bean like this and lazily initializes it:

```
@Autowired
private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

@Bean
@CustomerScoped
public Scheduler getScheduler() {
    CreateDefaults job = factory.createBean(CreateDefaults.class));
    Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
    scheduler.schedule(job);
    return scheduler;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    CustomerScope.setCustomer("tenant1");
    getScheduler();
    CustomerScope.setCustomer("tenant2");
    getScheduler();
    CustomerScope.clearCustomer();
}
```

When starting the server, two Schedulers should be created, each of which would execute their own instance of "Create Defaults".
When tenants access the application themselves, they should be getting their own instance of this Scheduler.
This seems to work but i wonder whether this is the correct way of doing things.
In particular, i am worried about the fact that the beanFactory isn't scoped itself.

Would this approach work and scale for more complex systems?

Comment: The factory doesn't need to be scoped, it only needs to be aware of the existing scopes so it can delegate storage/retrieval of beans to the scope.

Comment: How do i make the factory aware of the scope? Is it enough to have this in my config?

    `@Bean
    public static CustomScopeConfigurer customScope() {
        CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
        configurer.addScope(CustomerScope.CUSTOMER_SCOPE_NAME, new CustomerScope());

        return configurer;
    }`

Comment: Yes, that should be it. A configurer is a *"Simple `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` implementation that registers custom `Scope`(s) with the containing `ConfigurableBeanFactory`. "* - in spring-boot the `AutowireCapableBeanFactory`

Comment: Thank you, would you care to formulate this as an answer? I would be happy to mark it as "the" answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code sample was actually correct.
The Beanfactory doesn't need to be scoped itself, it just has to be made aware of the scope, which in my case can be achieved in the configuration:

```
@Bean 
public static CustomScopeConfigurer customScope() {
    CustomScopeConfigurer configurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
    configurer.addScope(CustomerScope.CUSTOMER_SCOPE_NAME, new CustomerScope()); 
    return configurer;
}
```